# In Tampermonkey using @require with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, require, tampermonkey

For the life of me I *cannot* get this to work.

I'm trying to write a userscript with tampermonkey that is @require'ing two jQuery resources - jQuery and jQuery UI.

Every single time, chrome's console gives me two to four errors, and they all looks like this:

core-c30de8a3f5468380db0b.js:1 GET about:blank net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

When I remove the two @requires, those errors go away.  I've tried it with and without the window.jQ, http and https, pulling from jQuery directly and the Google ajax version, I've tried running at document start and document idle, I've tried about everything.  All the rest of the script works, but requiring doesn't and obviously the jQuery bit doesn't.

Here is everything I have so far:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Score Graph
// @namespace    https://github.com/storjak
// @version      0.1
// @description  Score Graph
// @author       storjak
// @match        https://www.twitch.tv/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       @run-at document-start
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

// ==/UserScript==

window.jQ = $;

(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#container")
                .draggable({
                    handle: "#grab",
                    iframeFix: true,
                    containment: "document"
                });
        });
        appendButton();
    });

})();

// \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/  All this stuff works and can be ignored

function appendButton() {
    let chartStatus = false;
    let removedElement;
    let root = document.getElementById("root");
    const newButton = document.createElement("div");
    newButton.innerHTML = '<button style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin-right: 10px" class="ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonSecondary-sc-1qn4ixc-2 kMLrvA tw-core-button">Score Chart</button>';
    newButton.id = "score-graph-button";
    newButton.onclick = function scoreGraph() {
        if (chartStatus === false) {
            if (removedElement === undefined) {
                const src = "http://localhost:3000/userscript/" + location.pathname.slice(1);
                let newElement = document.createElement("div");
                newElement.style.cssText = "position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 100px; right: 10px; border: solid 1px black; border-radius: 8px; resize: both; overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 300px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;";
                newElement.id = "score-graph-container";
                newElement.innerHTML = '<div id="grab" style="background-color: #6441a5; border-bottom: solid 1px black; text-align: center; width: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 4px; cursor: move;">Drag Me!</div><div id="iframe-wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><iframe id="embed" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none;" title="Score Graph" src=' + src + '></iframe></div>';
                root.append(newElement);
            } else {
                root.append(removedElement);
            }
            chartStatus = true;
        } else if (chartStatus === true) {
            removedElement = document.getElementById("score-graph-container").remove();
            chartStatus = false;
        }
    }
    const navBar = document.getElementsByClassName("tw-align-items-center tw-flex tw-flex-grow-1 tw-flex-shrink-1 tw-full-width tw-justify-content-end");
    navBar[0].append(newButton);
}
```

I've been stuck on this for days and I'm about to lose my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested, working perfectly.
the require works alright maybe some other EXT or something is blocking ?

anyhow, fixed it a bit so the drag work as well.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.twitch.tv/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function appendButton() {
    let chartStatus = false;
    let removedElement;
    let root = document.getElementById("root");
    const newButton = document.createElement("div");
    newButton.innerHTML = '<button style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; margin-right: 10px" class="ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonSecondary-sc-1qn4ixc-2 kMLrvA tw-core-button">Score Chart</button>';
    newButton.id = "score-graph-button";
    newButton.onclick = function scoreGraph() {
        if (chartStatus === false) {
            if (removedElement === undefined) {
                const src = "http://localhost:3000/userscript/" + location.pathname.slice(1);
                let newElement = document.createElement("div");
                newElement.style.cssText = "position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 100px; right: 10px; border: solid 1px black; border-radius: 8px; resize: both; overflow: hidden; width: 300px; height: 300px; display: flex; flex-direction: column;";
                newElement.id = "score-graph-container";
                newElement.innerHTML = '<div id="grab" style="background-color: #6441a5; border-bottom: solid 1px black; text-align: center; width: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 4px; cursor: move;">Drag Me!</div><div id="iframe-wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><iframe id="embed" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none;" title="Score Graph" src=' + src + '></iframe></div>';
                root.append(newElement);
            } else {
                root.append(removedElement);
            }
            chartStatus = true;
        } else if (chartStatus === true) {
            removedElement = document.getElementById("score-graph-container").remove();
            chartStatus = false;
        }
    }
    const navBar = document.getElementsByClassName("tw-align-items-center tw-flex tw-flex-grow-1 tw-flex-shrink-1 tw-full-width tw-justify-content-end");
    navBar[0].append(newButton);
}


(function() {


    $(document).ready(function() {
        appendButton();
        $('body').on('click', '#grab', () => {
            $('#score-graph-container').draggable({
                handle: '#grab',
                iframeFix: true,
                containment: 'document'
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: I don't know what kind of magic you pulled but your version works perfectly fine, and I didn't change anything on my end, I just copy-pasted your version to my script file.  Just JS things, I guess.

Anyways, thank you greatly.